# Neo4J: Loading a csv file having large number of rows and columns, possible solutions?

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have a big CSV data file which consists of 20k records and 100+ columns and I want to load it in Neo4J. Now if I create one node for each record then I'll have 20k nodes each having 100+ properties. However at this point there will be no relationship among the nodes.
What I wish to do instead is, create nodes from columns (ofcourse duplicate values will be merged to one node) and a pseudo node (let's name it rowNode) for each record and create relationship between them. Now, I have 20k rowNodes each having 100 column nodes related to them.

The existing Load from CSV doesn't do it the way I want. I haven't found any tool that has this feature. The only way I can think of is writting a code to do it programmatically. Before going in that direction I wish to know there are other ways to achieve it. Any thoughts?

***Update:***
You can consider the following example:

```
id,name,age,occupation
1,John,50,businessman
2,mary,40,consultant
3,jack,45,architect
4,sarah,25,student
```

what i want to extract:

```
(rowNode)-[:relationship]->(name)
(rowNode)-[:relationship]->(age)
(rowNode)-[:relationship]->(occupation)
```

in this case:

```
(1)-[:hasname]->(john)
(1)-[:age]->(50)
```

and so on.

Comment: Could you share a small sample of the data set including what you expect to be created at the end of the import process?

Comment: are you sure that is how you want to design your database? I don't understand why you want to create node properties as relationships ..

Comment: @toine If you are referring to the example then you're right, they are properties of a person however in my real data set it's not the case. Rather they are connected entities and making relations make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid a programmatic solution, maybe you could check [Talend](http://www.talend.com/) (this is an ETL) connector for Neo4j:

- example [here](http://neo4j.com/blog/fun-with-music-neo4j-and-talend/)
- latest Talend Neo4j connector [release](http://www.talendforge.org/trac/tos/browser/tags/release-5_5_1/org.talend.designer.neo4j)
- current progress with Neo4j 2.x is tracked [here](https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-26871)

Comment: @Rolf- thanks, much appreciated, will try the TOS now.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally inadvisable to spread 100+ columns into as many nodes. Not only would you end up consuming a lot of overhead for storing possibly over 2 million nodes and an equal number of relationships, but processing multiple items of data for one row would be unnecessarily complex and slow. Also, visualizing your data (like in the neo4j Browser) could be very difficult, given the large number of nodes and relationships involved.

Generally, I would use a data model that kept the properties that are fairly specific to an entity within the same node. To follow your example: a `Person` node could have the properties `id`, `name`, and `age`. And a `Person` node could have a `WORKS_AS` relationship to an `Occupation` node -- one that could be related to many other `Person` nodes. This would reduce the number of nodes for each row from 4 to 2, and the number of relationships from 3 to 1. (And, actually, since the `Occupation` node would likely be shared by a large number of `Person` nodes, the number of nodes that "belong" to a row should really be considered to be 1 as well). This arrangement would also keep together within the same node the properties that are more likely to be needed by the same query.

Here is an example of how to load (in 1000-row chunks, to avoid running out of memory) the data from the csv file according to this sample data model:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '...uri...' AS line
MERGE (occ:Occupation {name: line.occupation})
CREATE
  (p:Person {
    id: TOINTEGER(line.id),
    name: line.name,
    age: TOINTEGER(line.age)
  })-[:WORKS_AS]->(occ);
```