# Neo4j server crashing on importing 70K rows from CSV. Unable to optimize the query

Tags: neo4j, graphql, neo4j-apoc

I'm quite new to neo4j and need some help in optimizing my import query. Currently, either the database connection crashes or it takes forever to run.

I have around 70K rows which are basically 25K unique nodes. I'm using the following script to import data and create relationships. The `csv` file itself is around `60MB`

**Creating constraints/indexes**

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.id IS UNIQUE
CREATE INDEX ON :Session(id)
CREATE INDEX ON :ReferrerType(id)
CREATE INDEX ON :Referrer(id)
CREATE INDEX ON :Landing(id)
CREATE INDEX ON :eventType(id)
CREATE INDEX ON :conversion(id)
```

**Import data**

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///df_all.csv' AS row
MERGE (p:Person {id: row._id})
MERGE (s:Session {id: row.sessionField})
MERGE (rt:ReferrerType {id: row.referer_type})
MERGE (rf:Referrer {id: row.refererField})
MERGE (l:Landing {id: row.location, device: row.browserName, firstTime: row.first})
MERGE (et:eventType {id: row.eventType, links: row.linkClick, scroll: row.scrollPage, button: row.buttonClick, search: row.visitorSearch, forms: row.formSubmission})
MERGE (cf:conversion {id: row.visitorEmail})
FOREACH(
  x IN CASE WHEN s.referer_type IS NULL OR NOT row.referer_type IN s.referer_type THEN [1] END | SET s.referer_type = COALESCE(s.referer_type, []) + row.referer_type
)
FOREACH(
  x IN CASE WHEN rf.location IS NULL OR NOT row.location IN rf.location THEN [1] END | SET rf.location = COALESCE(rf.location, []) + row.location
  )
FOREACH(
  x IN CASE WHEN l.eventType IS NULL OR NOT row.eventType IN l.eventType THEN [1] END | SET l.eventType = COALESCE(l.eventType, []) + row.eventType
  )
FOREACH(
  x IN CASE WHEN l.visitorEmail IS NULL OR NOT row.visitorEmail IN l.visitorEmail THEN [1] END | SET l.visitorEmail = COALESCE(l.visitorEmail, []) + row.visitorEmail
  )
MERGE (p)-[:HAS_SESSION]->(s)-[:REF_TYPE]->(rt)-[:FROM]->(rf)-[:LANDS_ON]->(l)-[:EVENT_DONE]->(et)<-[:VISITOR_TYPE]-(cf)
RETURN p, s, rt, rf, l, et, cf ORDER BY row._id,row.sessionField,row.timestamp
```

I'm not sure how else to optimize the query. I'm using a GCP VM with `8 cores and 30 GB Memory`. Most of the cores sit idle and not seeing memory consumption of more than 1-10GB

`Get this warning usually: The execution plan for this query contains the Eager operator`

Comment: There are too many merge clauses in a single query. Try creating/merging nodes and relationships separately in multiple queries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49644796/6124657

Comment: @Raj how am I supposed to break the query? As the merge statements are part of the load csv loop

Comment: To start with, you can merge nodes in the first query. In a second use match to find those nodes(just replace MERGE with MATCH) and MERGE the relationships.

Comment: If it still takes much time or doesn't work. Try to break down the query to MERGE only single-node/Relationship, instead of multiple nodes/relationships.